# How to open a http website with a Fancybox popup hosted on a https domain?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have an issue with Fancybox plugin where I want to open an `http://` external website via popup from my web page that is currently hosted on an `https://` domain. Is this possible with Fancybox?

My Fancybox head tag code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        iframe : {
            preload: false
        }
    });



$(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 1000,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '90%',
        height      : '90%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
    });



    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML inner link code is:

```
class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.saia.co.za/">www.saia.co.za
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can  open an http:// external website via popup of fancy box

it was made possible with the use of iframes

for more information please visit the link  http://fancybox.net/howto